# Renomear ficheiros a partir de uma lista txt

Tags: c#

Eu estou a tentar desenvolver um pequeno programa que me permita renomear um conjunto de ficheiros (tipo pdf existentes num dado diretório e cujo nome é sequencial: 001.pdf, 002.pdf, 003.pdf, etc), usando informação existente num ficheiro txt.

A informação existente no ficheiro txt é do seguinte género:

> "2500"    "_" "W1"    "001"   "E" "04"
>
> "2500"    "_" "W1"    "002"   "E" "05"
>
> "2500"    "_" "W1"    "003"   "E" "04"

O objetivo é que os ficheiros pdf sejam  renomeados com base nas linhas de texto do txt, não usando as aspas. Por exemplo o ficheiro 001.pdf ficaria 2500_W1001E04.pdf e assim sucessivamente.

O código que já possuo e que penso que poderá permitir ir mais longe é o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _utilitarios
{
    public partial class FormRenomear : Form
    {
        public FormRenomear()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Diretorio que contem os ficheiros pdf e o txt de referência para a renomeação dos ficheiros.
            string directory = @"C:\Users\arquivo1\arquivo2\";

            //Ficheiro do tipo txt que contém a lista para renomear os ficheiros.
            string filenames = File.ReadAllText(directory + "lista.txt");

            //Remove as aspas e separa por espaços.
            string[] listFilenames = filenames.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

            int i = 0; //Usado para aceder á lista de ficheiros.
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
            {
                //Ignorar o ficheiro txt.
                if (!file.EndsWith(".txt"))
                {
                    //Renomear o ficheiro.
                    File.Move(file, directory + listFilenames[i] + ".pdf");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual o seu problema ao certo? O que não está a funcionar no seu código?

Comment: O resultado que obtenho depois de correr o código, não é o que pretendo. Nos 3 exemplos, o que obtenho é os ficheiros renomeados assim: _.pdf ; 2500.pdf ; W1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no facto de não estarem a ser removidos os `TAB`.

Ao fazer o `Split('\t')` o texto está a ser dividido pelo `TAB` ao invés de remover o `TAB` e depois dividir por quebra de linha.

A solução poderá passar por substituir a linha:

```
string[] listFilenames = filenames.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');
```

Por esta:

```
string[] listFilenames = filenames.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty).Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Excelente! Isso mesmo! Obrigado.